# Computing Chern Classes of Tautological Line Bundles

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles

I cannot find any references with how to handle this tautological line bundle $V \rightarrow P(\mathbb{H}^2)$ where $\mathbb{H}$ are the Hamilton quaternions.

I know it is a complex rank 2 vector bundle, so the total chern class is $1 + e(V_\mathbb{R})$ and the top chern class is $c_2(V) = e(V_{\mathbb{R}})$, so $c_0(V) = 1, c_1(V) = 0$ but I want to know what $c_2(V)$ is.

Does anyone have an idea for approaching this?

I think it I should use the splitting principle. From Bott and Tu, we can use the complex projectivization of V as a splitting manifold. And we know this is diffeomorphic to $P(\mathbb{C}^4)$

Comment: Dear mathdragon, Just to check, $\mathbb H$ denotes the Hamilton quaternions?  Regards,

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'll edit to add that.

Comment: Dear mathdragon, One more thing: if the fibres are $\mathcal H$-lines in $\mathcal H$ (which I would guess they are, since this is the usual definition of the tautological bundle), then aren't they $2$-dimensional over $\mathbb C$, making $V$ a rank $2$ complex *vector bundle*?  (You write *line bundle* in your post, which is why I am asking.)  Regards,

Comment: Matt, you're right. Again, sorry. I should have read that over more before posting.

Comment: I'll add this to the top, but I think it I should use the splitting principle. From Bott and Tu, we can use the complex projectivization of V as a splitting manifold. And we know this is diffeomorphic to $P(\mathbb{C}^4)$

Comment: Possibly a silly question, but what complex structure on $\Bbb H^2$ are you considering? I ask because it seems to me it would have to to be compatible with quaternion multiplication, and $\Bbb H$ isn't a $\Bbb C$ algebra (in any natural way that I'm aware of).

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Dear Olivier, I was bit confused about this at first, but isn't it the case that this is canonically a bundle of $1$-dimensional $\mathbb H$-modules, and by fixing a copy of $\mathbb C$ inside $\mathbb H$ (which is somewhat canonical, since they're all conjugate in $\mathbb H$) we can regard it as a bundle of rank $2$ complex vector spaces?  Regards,

Comment: Dear mathdragon, I would guess that $c_2$ is equal to the cohomology class of $P(\mathbb H)$ inside $P(\mathbb H^2)$, or perhaps its negative (I'm unsure about the conventions being used right now), and I might be able to prove it, starting from the definition I'm most comfortable with, which is definitely *not* the splitting principle.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE I'm not really sure to be honest, but I would like to hear from mathdragon.

Comment: @MattE I guess you're right, that should settle it. Just fix a copy of $\Bbb C$ inside the coefficient field $\Bbb H$, and any $\Bbb H$-vector space becomes a $\Bbb C$-vector space. Silly me.

Comment: Could it be $0$? I know there are caracteristic classes similar to the Chern classes for quaternion vector bundles (for quaternion line bundles there is one class $p_1$ of degree $4$), and maybe there is the same phenomenon as with the Pontryaguine classes, that they vanish half of the time? This is pure speculation.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: Dear Olivier, What you write would be consisent with $c_1(V) = 0$ (which I think can also be thought of as being caused by the fact that an $\mathbb H$-line bundle, when though of as a complex vector bundle, is actually an $SU(2)$-bundle, and so its determinant is trivial).  But I don't think it would cause $c_2$ to vanish, since this would presumably be exactly be the degree $4$ class you're thinking of. Cheers,

Comment: @MattE Yes, although I wrote quite the opposite, this is what I meant to say ^^ (the vanishing of the first Chern class). Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really $100\%$ sure my solution is correct, also, there remains an indeterminacy in the end result: I don't quite identify the class you are looking for in $P^1\Bbb H\simeq \Bbb S^4$, only up to sign.

---

Let $Q$ be the projectivisation of $p:V\rightarrow P^1\Bbb H$. As you note, $Q$ is isomorphic to $P^3\Bbb C$. To be precise, we consider $\Bbb C\subset \Bbb H$ through $1,i\mapsto 1,i$ respectively. Thanks to the standard left $\Bbb H$-vector space structure on $\Bbb H^2$, $\Bbb H^2$ can be seen as a complex vector space  isomorphic $\Bbb C^4$. Now by definition of $Q$ we get a homeomorphism
$$\begin{array}{rcl}Q=\coprod_{S\subset\Bbb H^2}P(S)&\longleftrightarrow &P^3\Bbb C\\ l&\mapsto&l\\l\in P(\Bbb H\cdot l)&\gets&l\end{array}$$
The direct sum is taken over all quaternionic (left) lines $S$, and for every such line $S$, $P(S)$ is the complex projective space on $S$.

The pullback bundle of $V$ over $Q$ splits into two complex line bundles $L\oplus L'$ ver $Q$, with the fiber of $L$ over $l$ being $l$ itself, so that (modulo the above isomorphism), $$L\text{ is isomorphic to the tautological line bundle over }P^3\Bbb C$$

@Matt E gave a convincing argument for the vanishing of the first Chern class of $V$. Computing the total Chern class of the pullback bundle gives $$\pi^*(1+c_2(V))=c(L\oplus L')=c(L)c(L')=1+c_1(L)+c_1(L')+c_1(L)c_1(L')$$ The class $c_1(L)+c_1(L')$ vanishes, and it follows (I believe) that $L'\simeq L^*$, since both are line bundles, and thus completely caracterized by their first Chern class. If $c$ is the standard degree $2$ generator of $H^3(Q)=H^2(P^3(\Bbb C))$ (i.e. the first Chern class of the tautological line bundle over $P^3(\Bbb C)$), then $$\pi^*(c_2(V))=-c^2.$$

---

It remains to understand $\pi$. The canonical map $Q\to P^1\Bbb H$ is a fibration. Actually, it is obtained from the Hopf fibration $\Bbb S^3\hookrightarrow\Bbb S^7\hookrightarrow\Bbb S^4$ by quotienting out the action of $\Bbb S^1$).
$$\begin{array}{rc}\Bbb S^2\simeq P^1\Bbb C\hookrightarrow & P^3(\Bbb C)\\&\downarrow\\ &\Bbb S^4\end{array}$$
The associated spectral sequence collapses at rank $2$ because of how the nonzero nodes are placed, and this tells us that the cohomology of $\Bbb S^4$ in degree $4$ is isomorphic to that of $P^3\Bbb C$ in degree $4$ through $\pi^*$. Since $\pi^*(c_2(V))=-c^2$ is a generator in degree $4$, we necessarily have $c_2(V)=$ one of the two generators of $H^4(\Bbb S^4)$ . I don't know which one this is.

Comment: Dear Olivier, This looks good to me; I was also a bit unsure about the sign.  Part of the issue perhaps is that one has to figure out how $P(\mathbb H^2)$ is oriented in the first place.  I guess the quaternionic situation is something like the complex situation, where one gets a canonical orientation (?) .  
Regards,

Comment: @MattE I would put my money on the opposite of the canonical generator of $H^4(\Bbb S^4)$, but I'm going to bed right now ^^

Comment: Dear Olivier, I agree, based on the analogy with complex projective case.  Cheers,